# SQL: How to select pass rows from student table in case of re-sit exam in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Say I have a table which has the data of students and their results.

```
ID  Result
1   PASS
2   PASS
3   PASS
3   FAIL
4   PASS
4   FAIL
4   FAIL
5   FAIL
5   FAIL
5   FAIL
```

And I want to select one row for each student if they pass, I want pass rows to return but if they don't then return one fail row.

This is the expected result:

```
ID  Result
1   PASS
2   PASS
3   PASS
4   PASS
5   FAIL
```

**Note:** Students can re-sit the exam as many times as they wish until they get a pass or give up from the exam.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a `GROUP BY`. Since `PASS` (always) is greater than `FAIL`, use `MAX()`.

```
select ID, max(Result)
from tablename
group by ID
```

Comment: @jarlh Can you explain what you mean by saying PASS is (always) greater than FAIL? In my case 'PASS' and 'FAIL' are string though. Would it still work?

Comment: @bensw The string 'PASS' is greater than the string 'FAIL'.

Comment: And it's also greater to pass an examination than to fail.

Answer (score 1):

In this case a simple `group by id` to get the maximum result will do:

```
select 
  id,
  max(result) result
from tablename
group by id
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_8.4&fiddle=73962f4d1080fedd3e9f78e2ce39a7cb).
Results:

```
> id | result
> -: | :-----
>  1 | PASS  
>  2 | PASS  
>  3 | PASS  
>  4 | PASS  
>  5 | FAIL
```

Answer (score 0):

use corelated subquery and union

```
select id,result from tbl
where result='pass'
union 
select id,result from tbl
where not exists( select 1 from tbl t2 where t1.id=t2id 
                    and result='pass')
```

or you could use row_number() analytic function

```
select id,result from
(select id,result,
  row_number() over(partition by id order by case when result='pass' then 1 else 2 end) rn
 ) where rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use EXISTS:

```
select distinct ID, 
       case when exists (select 1 from MyTable t2 where t1.ID = T2.ID and T2.Result = 'Pass') then 'Pass' else 'Fail' end as Result
from MyTable t1
```

Answer (score 0):

OK,a PG-style way to implement this requirement is to use array function, like below:

```
select 
    id,
    case when array_agg(distinct result)::varchar[] @> array['PASS']::varchar[] then 'PASS' else 'FAIL' end as result 
from 
    test 
group by 
    id;
 id | result 
----+--------
  1 | PASS
  2 | PASS
  3 | PASS
  4 | PASS
  5 | FAIL
```

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this with the following:

```
   select id, max(result)
   from tbl
   group by id
```